# Does the process of sending custom telemtry to Application insighst considered ETL?

Tags: etl, azure-application-insights

Basically the title .
When we send custom telemetry to application insights from our application , will it be considered an ETL process?

Comment: Exactly why is it you want to know that? Anyway, I don't think it is. It is just an api.

Comment: I was working on project with application insights to send custom telemetry and wanted to make a comparative analysis of using other options like stream analytics where there is ETL. Hence wanted to know

Comment: can [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation#enable-w3c-distributed-tracing-support-for-net-apps) be of some help?

Comment: @TinyWang hey thanks , i am still not very sure but as Peter said I think it shouldn't be

Comment: @PeterBons Could you pls add your thoughts as the answer to end this case sir ? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls allow me sum up here to end this question.

As @PeterBons said in the comment. Although there's no official document to prove but assumed by experience, sending custom telemetry to app insights seems calling an API.